# Bounding the maximum of the sum of squared iid. normal variables

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to work my way through a proof and I am stuck on the following problem:

Assume for $i = 1, \dots, p$ that $x_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. For a binary $p$-dimensional vector $\gamma$ define: 
$$
\|x_\gamma\|_{\ell_2}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^p \gamma_i x_i^2
$$
ie. the sum of the squares of the elements of $x$ where $\gamma$ is non-zero and let $|\gamma| = \sum_{i=1}^p \gamma_i$ be the number of non-zero elements in $\gamma$. Let
$$
A = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^p : \|x_\gamma\|_{\ell_2}^2 \leq 4 \sigma^2 (1+a) |\gamma| \log p, \forall \gamma \in \{0,1\}^p \right\}
$$
I want to show:
$$
P(A) > 1 - \frac{1}{p^a \sqrt{\pi \log p}}
$$
Ie. with probability at least $1 - \frac{1}{p^a \sqrt{\pi \log p}}$, $\|x_\gamma\|_{\ell_2}^2 \leq 4 \sigma^2 (1+a)|\gamma| \log p$ for all $\gamma$.

One idea is first to define the maximum $m = \max_i \{x_i^2\}$, then use $\|x_\gamma\|_{\ell_2}^2 \leq |\gamma| m$, and apply Markov's inequality on $m$ (requiring the expectation of $m$ which I don't know) to get a bound for $A$, however I haven't been able to get very far and I am not sure it is the right approach. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which assumption about dependence of the $x_i$ to you do?

Comment: I assume the $x_i$ are iid. normally distributed.

Comment: Okay I just noticed there is an obvious problem with the bound if $p = 1$; it need only be shown to hold if $p$ is large. P. 1576 of the following article may be relevant: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdfview_1&handle=euclid.aos/1216237292